# Setting up audio unit iOS with mono input and stereo output

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to set up an audio unit capable of mono input and stereo output. Intend on playing a sine wave tone through the left channel output and a different sign wave periodically through the right channel out.

I am receiving the error,

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ' Error initialing unit: -50;
```

when I attempt to initialize my audio unit here,

```
// Initialize audio unit
OSErr err = AudioUnitInitialize(self.ioUnit);
NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %hd", err);
```

I believe it has to do with how I am setting up the audio unit,

```
// Audio component description
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags         = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

// Get component
AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

// Get Audio units
AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &ioUnit);

// Enable input, which disabled by default. Output enable by default
UInt32 enableInput = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit,
                     kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                     kInputBus,
                     &enableInput,
                     sizeof(enableInput));

AudioStreamBasicDescription monoStreamFormat;
monoStreamFormat.mSampleRate          = 44100.00;
monoStreamFormat.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
monoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags         = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;
monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket      = 2;
monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame       = 2;
monoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket     = 1;
monoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame    = 1;
monoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel      = 16;

// Apply format to input of ioUnit
AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                     kInputBus,
                     &monoStreamFormat,
                     sizeof(monoStreamFormat));


AudioStreamBasicDescription stereoStreamFormat;
stereoStreamFormat.mSampleRate          = 44100.00;
stereoStreamFormat.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
stereoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags         = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;
stereoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket      = 4;
stereoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame       = 4;
stereoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket     = 1;
stereoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame    = 2;
stereoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel      = 32;

// Apply format to output of ioUnit
AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                     kOutputBus,
                     &stereoStreamFormat,
                     sizeof(stereoStreamFormat));

// Set input callback
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = inputCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     kInputBus,
                     &callbackStruct,
                     sizeof(callbackStruct));

// Set output callback
callbackStruct.inputProc = outputCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     kOutputBus,
                     &callbackStruct,
                     sizeof(callbackStruct));
```

but I couldn't find anything on the error code -50 it's giving back so I'm not sure what it doesn't like. I'm on a deadline so any help it greatly appreciated.

Comment: -50 is `paramErr` : Error in user parameter list

Comment: Thank you for the response but I don't see where that could be occurring in my code, do you @sbooth? `$ macerror -50` agrees with you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical is 32-bit 8.24 fixed point format. That means mBytesPerFrame should be 4 for mono and 8 for stereo, and mBitsPerChannel should be 32 for both stereo and mono. Setting it to 16-bits for would probably produce this error.

That said, I doubt you want 8.24. You probably want kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical to get standard 16-bit audio. Or, if you want 32 bit, go with 32-bit float (kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved). Easier to deal with the math during your processing.

Also, you are setting the formats on the virtual inputs and outputs rather than the client inputs and outputs, which I don't think is what you want. The API here is rather confusing, but to set client input format, use kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus. The logic here is that you're setting the format of the *output* of the internal Core Audio *input* converter unit, which, from the perspective of your code, is the input audio. Confusing, I know. See Audio Unit docs for more detail. Likewise, to set client output format, use kAudioUnitScope_Output, kInputBus.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will make those changes to the IO formats and see if it fixes my error (you're right that the naming is counterintuitive for the IO formats).

Comment: I'm assuming based on your response that I also need to switch `kOutputBus` with `kInputBus` when setting up my IO callbacks as well.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. mBytesPerFrame should be 8 for stereo with 8.24.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think so. I've only ever set up a single callback, which I think is all you need really. You get input samples, process them, and then output them, all in the same callback. So it would be kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus.

Comment: Note that for enabling input, you *do* use input scope and input bus however.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I took your advice about changing from `kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical` and I'm now using `kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked`. The error is gone and I'm now getting input but no output. I'm going to mark your answer as the accepted answer. I'm hoping I can continue picking your brain. Are you on IRC or any other chat service? I don't want to take up to much of your time, but my deadline for this is today and any help I can get it greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped. Post another question to stack overflow if you can't find the answer elsewhere on here. I'll keep an eye out...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50809/discussion-between-studmuf-and-adam-bryant)

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

32 bits per channel is too many bits to fit 2 channels into 4 bytes.  Try 16.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but I still get the same `error: -50` during the initialization call ( `AudioUnitInitialize(self.ioUnit)` ).

Comment: @hotpaw2- any other ideas?